Blender 3.0 I am having a problem while adding empty
My empty always appears as a small dot and does not work correctly during any project but it occurs completely fine in an empty 3d viewport but not during projects.


Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see What should I do if no one answers my question?

Expand the operator properties window at the bottom left and increase the Radius parameter.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos He appears to have just deleted his previous question and the operator properties dropdown is bottom-left, not bottom-right! :^)

My problem is mostly solved thanks for your guidance, the only thing I am facing now is it still doesn't work when I import a city model from sketch fab. I believe this is occurring due to the import . Is their anyway to solve this also?
